# OpenCL / OpenGL Implicit Synchronization on AMD Tahiti

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl, amd-gpu

I'm having a problem with the "implicit synchronization" of OpenCL and OpenGL on an AMD Tahiti (AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series) device. The device has the cl/gl extensions, `cl_khr_gl_sharing`, and `cl_khr_gl_event`.

When I run the program which is just a simple vbo update kernel, and draw it as a white line with simple shader, it hiccups like crazy, stalling what looks to be 2-4 frames every update.  I can confirm that it isn't the cl kernel or gl shader that I'm using to update and draw the buffer, because if I put `glFinish` and `commandQueue.finish()` before and after the acquire and release of gl objects for the cl update, everything works as it should.

So, I figured that I needed to "enable" the event extension...

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_gl_event : enable
```

...in the cl program, but that throws errors. I assume this extension isn't a client facing extension and is supposed to just work as "expected", which is why I can't enable it.

The third behavior that I noticed is that if I take out the `glFinish()` and `commandQueue.finish()`, and run it in CodeXL debug, the implicit synchronization works. As in, without any changes to the code base, like forcing synchronization with finish, CodeXL allows for implicit synchronization. So, implicit sync clearly works, but I can't get it to work by just running the application regularly through Visual Studio and forcing synchronization.

Clearly I'm missing something, but I honestly can't see it. Any thoughts or explanations would be greatly appreciated, as I'd love to keep the synchronization implicit.

Comment: _The third behavior that I noticed...if I take out the glFinish() and commandQueue.finish(), and run it in CodeXL debug, the implicit synchronization works._ Are you positive? Since this is a debugger, I'd be inclined to believe it runs in lock-step rather than queuing 3-4 frames worth of commands like the driver ordinarily would (AMD calls this the Flip Queue Size in their driver). I believe a `glFinish (...)` command is effectively inserted in the command stream every time you swap buffers in CodeXL (if it's anything like gDEBugger was).

Comment: That would then definitely explain where the synchronization is coming from but still doesn't explain why the Device isn't allowing implicit synchronization from the cl_khr_gl_event extension.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're not using the GLsync-cl_event synchro (`GL_ARB_cl_event` and `cl_khr_gl_event` extensions), which is why adding cl/glFinish and the overhead from CodeXL are helping.

My guess is your code looks like:

```
A1. clEnqueueNDRangeKernel
A2. clEnqueueReleaseObjects
[here is where you inserted clFinish]
B1. glDraw*
B2. wgl/glXSwapBuffers
[here is where you inserted glFinish]
C1. clEnqueueAcquireObjects
[repeat from A1]
```

Instead, you should:

1. CL->GL synchro: have `clEnqueueReleaseObjects` create an (output) event to be passed to `glCreateSyncFromCLeventARB`, then use `glWaitSync` (NOT `glClientWaitSync` - which in this case would be the same as `clFinish`).
2. GL->CL synchro: have `clEnqueueAcquireObjects` take an (input) event, which will be created with `clCreateFromGLsync`, taking a sync object from `glFenceSync`

Overall, it should be:

```
A1. `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`

[Option 1.1:]
A2. `clEnqueueReleaseObjects`( ..., 0, NULL, &eve1)

[Option 1.2:]
A2. `clEnqueueReleaseObjects`( ..., 0, NULL, NULL)
A2'. `clEnqueueMarker`(&eve1)

A3. sync1 = glCreateSyncFromCLeventARB(eve1)
* clReleaseEvent(eve1)
A4. glWaitSync(sync1)
* glDeleteSync(sync1)
B1. glDraw*
B2. wgl/glXSwapBuffers
B3. sync2 = glFenceSync
B4. eve2 = clCreateFromGLSync(sync2)
* glDeleteSync(sync2)

[Option 2.1:]
C1. clEnqueueAcquireObjects(, ..., 1, &eve2, NULL)
* clReleaseEvent(eve2)

[Option 2.2:]
B5. clEnqueueWaitForEvents(1, &eve2)
* clReleaseEvent(eve2)
C1. clEnqueueAcquireObjects(, ..., 0, NULL, NULL)

[Repeat from A1]
```

(Options 1.2 / 2.2 are better if you don't exactly know in advance what will be the last enqueue before handing control over to the other API)

As a side note, I assumed you're not using an out-of-order queue for OpenCL (there really shouldn't be a need for one in this case) - if you did, you of course have to also synchro `clEnqueueAcquire` -> `clEnqueueNDRange` -> `clEnqueueRelease`.

Comment: I understand using the glSync and clEvent explicit synchronization behavior. However, from the OpenCL extension (cl_khr_gl_event), it says"...this extension modifies the behavior of clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects and clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects to implicitly guarantee synchronization with an OpenGL context bound in the same thread..." That's why I believe the CodeXL works as expected. Some switch is flipped that isn't flipped automatically. I guess what I'm wondering is, Why should I have to create the explicit synchronization, when implicit is supported? Or is this an AMD bug?

Comment: Correct; if these extension exists you don't need the clFinish / glFinish calls, per the section of the spec you quoted. However, only if you're doing work on the same thread. Is that the case?